# Converting object space normal mappingto tangent space normal mapping

Tags: three.js

I need to convert object space normal mapping (1st image) to tangent space normal mapping (2nd image).

HAVE
[image]

NEED
[image]

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Typically you provide a per vertex normal and tangent vector which are used to form the basis vectors T, B, N (tangent, binormal, and normal). The provided normal from the normal map is defined in this T-B-N coordinate system and shading is computed in this space. I can explain how that is done if you wish, but I am not sure if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Look into software called 'handplane' but you will need the original mesh. Rebaking in maya or max, choosing tangent space instead of object will also do the trick.

Comment: http://www.xnormal.net/5.aspx seems to do the job. (middle of page)

Comment: thx for answers. do i understand correctly that there is no method to convert this only on image base and i always need an original mesh?
I have problem with performance, this mesh is generated landscape with millions of vertices and i havent hardware to handle with it. This is the reason why i trying to use most simple mesh and using normal maps, but, i need to use tangent map for three js as i understood today. But i get only space normal map with this meshes. (one map 100MB)

Comment: xnormal.net/5.aspx  did the trick wit the low poly mesh. Thx @gaitat